# Determining the values of $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ in the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have been given this power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(4+x)^{n}}{4^{n+2}}$$
And I was told that the series converges for $a < x < b$ which I found as well:
$$-8<x<0$$
I have also been told that for $a < x < b$, the sum of the series is:
$$S(x)=-\frac{c_{1}+x}{c_{2}{x+c_{3}}}$$

How can I find the values of $c1, c2, c3$?

Comment: This is a geometric series, do you know how to evaluate it?

Comment: The formula for $S(x)$ cannot be right, it should diverge to infinity for $x=-8$. (The sum of a geometric series is a rational function of the common ratio.)

Comment: I suppose that it should read $S(x)=-\frac{c_{1}+x}{c_{2}(x+c_{3})}$

Comment: In the exercise, it is states as the one I have written in the question. Can I ask what is wrong with it?

Comment: I gave two reasons !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note :* $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n(4+x)^n}{4^{n+2}}\implies\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{-4-x}{4}\right)^n$$

It is nothing but *Infinite Geometric Progression* . [*note :* Sum of Infinite GP is $\frac{a}{1-r}$ iff $|r|<1$] $$\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{\frac{-4-x}{4}}{1+\frac{4+x}{4}}\right) \text{ iff } |-4-x|<4$$

OR $$\implies-\frac{4+x}{128+16x}$$

Finally we need to compare it with $$-\frac{c_1+x}{c_2x+c_3}$$

Hence $\color{red}{c_1=4}$ , $\color{red}{c_2=16}$ and $\color{red}{c_3=128}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanation!

Comment: @DiscoCarl No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** With $t:=\dfrac{4+x}4$, we get a familiar series:

$$\dfrac 1{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-t)^n=-\frac t{16(1+t)}\text{ for }-1<t<1.$$

---

Alternatively, we know that the function has a pole at $x=-8$, and we observe that it vanishes for $x=-4$. Hence it must be of the form

$$S(x)=c\frac{x+4}{x+8}.$$

We get the constant $c$ by evaluating at $x=-5$,

$$S(-5)=\frac1{12}=c\frac{-5+4}{-5+8}.$$

Comment: This might be a stupid question. Why is 16 in the denominator not raised because in S(x) it is raised with x+c3?

Comment: @DiscoCarl: I told you that the formula is wrong.

Comment: @PatBol So , what are your final conclusions for $c_1$ , $c_2$ and $c_3$ ?